# Java Collection LinkedList Function Argument Types

Tags: java, generics, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic)

I noticed that few of the LinkedList operations take Generic parameter type E, while a few take 'Object' as the parameter. For ex,

```
add(E e) 
remove(Object o)
```

Is there a specific reason to do that? Why not make 'remove' take a generic type E. (I know it doesn't matter after type erasure, but just wondering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the add and remove methods are inherited from the Collection interface. The remove method was not retrofitted with a generic argument presumably because it wouldn't matter. Remove doesn't affect the type safety of the collection and when you're changing one of the most popular APIs on the planet, fewer changes are better. You'll see that the contains method suffered the same fate as well.

Comment: "because it wouldn't matter" It *does* matter. Objects of different types can be equal.

Comment: It _won't_ matter because objects of different types can never be added to the parameterized collection, therefore requiring that the remove method be parameterized gains you nothing.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the things added to the collection. It's just that the definition of the `remove()` method requires that it removes stuff that is equal to the thing passed

Answer (score 1):

This is because **removal** operation checks for equality using `equals()` method and `equals()` method takes in an Object as parameter not generic .

Answer (score 0):

Because the caller can call `remove` or `contains` using any type of object and the code will still perform just fine. The compile time contract that the type parameter of collections uses just guarantees* that anything **in** the collection will be of the given type. It doesn't care about whether you ask it if it contains an object of a different type.

*Nitpicker's Corner, I know that Java generics really aren't a guarantee. More of syntactic sugar I suppose.