# Inconsistent arguments in ArrayList methods

Tags: java

In ArrayList API **add()** takes an argument of generic parameter type, but **contains()** and **indexOf()** take arguments of type **Object**.

```
public class ArrayList<E> ...{
     public boolean add(E e);  
     public boolean contains(Object o);
     public int indexOf(Object o);
     ....
}
```

[Java Doc for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

So i am just wondering if its something to do with Generics or it's design in-consistency ?

I looked at **Openjdk** implementation but couldn't find any specific reason for this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What the API is saying is that:

1. You can't `add()` anything that isn't an `E`;
2. You are, however, allowed to go searching for things that are not `E` (but that could compare equal to an instance of `E`).

Consider the following example:

```
public class Main {
    public static class Key {
        private final int k;
        public Key(int k) {
            this.k = k;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof Key)) {
                return false;
            }
            Key rhs = (Key)obj;
            return k == rhs.k;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            //...
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public static class Data extends Key {
        private final int d;
        public Data(int k, int d) {
            super(k);
            this.d = d;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> l = new ArrayList<Data>();
        l.add(new Data(123, 456));
        l.add(new Data(42, 24));
        System.out.println(l.contains(new Key(789)));
        System.out.println(l.contains(new Key(123)));
        System.out.println(l.contains(new Key(42)));
    }
}
```

The last three lines wouldn't compile if `contains()` were restricted to taking `Data`.

Comment: but what's point in searching for anything when compiler ensures that you can put only E ?

Comment: @rai.skumar you could go searching for a supertype of `E`.  For instance, you could have a `List<Integer>` and a `Number`, and be able to check if that `Number` is in the `List`

Comment: @rai.skumar: I've added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good explanation: [Why does Set.contains() take an Object, and not E?](http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html)