# Why List.contains() takes Object as an argument in Collections Java

Tags: java, list, object, collections

The `java.util.List.contains(Object o)` method takes `Object` as an argument and internally uses `Object.equals(Object o)` as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

If I do the following code in Netbeans:

```
 List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<>();
 listStr.contains(34); //warning
```

it gives the **obvious** warning, that is:

```
Given object can not contain instances of int (expected String)
```

Since it visible to all, that `String` never be equal to `int` then why shouldn't it take **Element type** `E` (in my case `String`) as an argument instead of `Object`?

Comment: Alternatively http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic - same deal with maps

Comment: @thobens: I do not believe this has to do with generics.

Comment: @staticx: Depends on what you think is the question. If you look at the title, this is the exact same issue...

Comment: @thobens: Afraid not. `int` is boxed up to `Object`. That's not generics... that's just the mechanics of Java.

Comment: @staticx: Yeah, obviously. But the question is **why it takes an Object instead of the Element Type `E`**, and thus making it possible to use an `int` (or every other type) instead of a `String`. At least this is how I understand the question.

Comment: Can OP please clarify?

Comment: @staticx: have you googled the google talk mentioned in the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic ?

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic but arguably not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking such an implementation would be wrong.

The reason for this is that even if an object is not of type `E`, it could still return `true` on an `equals()` call.

Assume for a second, that you've got a class like this:

```
public class FakeString {
  private final String value;

  public FakeString(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return value.hashCode();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return value.equals(o);
  }
}
```

Then this code would print `true`:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
System.out.println(strings.contains(new FakeString("bar")));
```

And just to clarify: this behaviour is **intended** and is the reason why `contains()` takes an `Object` instead of `E`. The same is true for `remove()`, by the way.

---

Your `int` will be boxed to an `Object`.

`(int) === boxing ===> (Integer) ==== reference widening ===> (Object)`

But Netbeans is smart and detects this, notices that your `Integer` is incompatible with a `String`. Normally this would throw a `ClassCastException`. However, the javadoc clearly states that throwing the ClassCastException on [Collections.contains(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is optional.

So in this case, there would be no benefit to overload the `contains` method to allow an `Element` type because `int`, `float`, `double`, etc can be autoboxed to `Object` successfully. Therefore, a `contains` with just `Object` is just fine.

---

For reasons unknown, `List`, `HashSet`, `Set`, and `LinkedHashSet` do not throw a `ClassCastException` if ***"f the type of the specified element is incompatible with this [insert type here] (optional)"***. Note the ***optional*** part. As you have shown, Netbeans will give you a suspicious warning when you try to pass an incompatible type. The trap here is if you try to use logic to rely on the return value of `.contains(...)`. A developer who doesn't pay attention to his warnings could fall into the trap of assuming that `contains` will always ***work***, but then it doesn't.

As the developer at this [blog](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/04/contains-trap-in-java-collections.html) recommends, here are four steps to avoid this pitfall in the future:

> 1. Careful coding and code reviews might lead to developers or reviewers seeing that an object of an irrelevant class is being passed
>      to the contains method. I'm typically uncomfortable leaving it with
>      just this form of protection.
> 2. Use of a modern version of NetBeans or of similar tools that flag the "suspicious" behavior can be very helpful.
> 3. Unit tests combined with code coverage tests can be helpful in identifying seemingly strange flows through the code that can be
>      attributed to issues such as the one described in this post.
> 4. Collection implementations that do throw ClassCastException at least provide a runtime error to let developers know that an improper
>      action is being taken. It may not be as effective as compile-time
>      detection, but it does make it much easier to identify that there is a
>      problem and what it is when it happens then without it. However, the
>      major disadvantage with this approach is that the choice of which
>      collection implementation to use is often driven by important
>      considerations that often outweigh the desire to have runtime
>      detection of an errant call to contains.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you can do this:

```
List<?> listStr = new ArrayList<>();
```

In this case you don't know what is the type, so it would not be possible verify that an element is contained in this list if the type T were take as argument instead of a object. This would break the use of wildcards.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I think it answer the question. I meant that this way you could not use wildcards

Comment: That's not the reason or the crux of this question and has nothing to do with it.

Comment: of course this is the crux of the question. He asked the reason for contains() receive and object and not a generic type ("then why shouldn't it take Element type E as an argument instead of Object?"), and this was what I answered.

Comment: Fair enough, you are right in that regard.

Comment: could you remove the down vote?

Comment: I can't because you would have to edit it (system won't let me) and you could add more to this answer to make it better anyways.

Comment: now I think its better.