# Java Arraylist remove method takes Object as parameter, not E

Tags: java, arraylist, generic-collections

For a typed ArrayList `list<E>` , why isn't remove method is like

```
public boolean remove(E e) {
}
```

remove() and contains() method takes Object o as parameter. while add() takes E.
There is a likelihood someone can call remove() with different object type and get Runtime Error.

Comment: No. There is **absolutely no chance** that calling `remove` with any type will cause a `ClassCastException`. All `remove` does is loop through the `List` and test `equals` against each element. There are no operations that will involve casting - if `equals` is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arraylist actually stores the items in an Object array:

`Object[] elementData;`

In the remove() method, it does a comparison with the items in the array using the equals method comparing 2 objects, and if nothing is found it doesn't do anything. (and does not throw a Runtime Error as you believe) It doesn't need to care about if the types match what is in the array.

Also, paraphrasing the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10790275/792238), if we had an `ArrayList<Cat> cats`, and `Cat extends Animal`, then we should be able to call the remove on cats the following way:

`Animal siameseCat = new Cat("purrykitty");
cats.remove(siameseCat);`

If remove enforced that it take only an object of type `Cat`, then this removal would've thrown an error despite being a reasonable request.

The add() method on the other hand needs to ensure that the array does not contain mismatched items.