# HashSet contains not working for Integer

Tags: java

I don't understand why the contains is not working (in fact if I had passed in custom class I could have revisited my hascode and equals method but this is Integer). So instead of contains what can I use? Please help.

```
Set<Integer> st = new HashSet<>();
st.add(12);
Set<Integer> st1 = new HashSet<>();
st1.add(12);
System.out.println(st.contains(st1));
```

Comment: The confusion is caused by the `contains` method expecting an `Object`, and not an `Integer`. So the root cause is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic

Comment: `st.contains(st1)` checks is `st` contains the object `st1` (wich is `Set<Integer>`), but you just add `12` to it, not `st1`

Answer (score 8):

`st.contains(st1)` returns `false`, because the type of `st1` (`Set<Integer>`) is not the same as the type of the elements in `st` (which is `Integer`).

You can, however, use the [`Set#containsAll(Collection<?>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) method:

```
System.out.println(st.containsAll(st1));
```

which will check if the elements of `st1` are present in `st`.

Answer (score 5):

`st1` is a `HashSet` not an `Integer`.

try it with that code and you will see it works:

```
Set<Integer> st = new HashSet<>();
st.add(12);
System.out.println(st.contains(12));
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> st = new HashSet<>();
    st.add(12);
    Set<Integer> st1 = new HashSet<>();
    st1.add(12);
    System.out.println(st.containsAll(st1));
  }
```