# Why Collection class methods contains() and remove() don't use generic types in parameters?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Why methods

```
boolean contains(Object o)
boolean remove(Object o)
```

aren't defined like

```
boolean add(E e)
```

using generic type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic?rq=1