# Set have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other error

Tags: java, collections, compiler-errors, set, overloading

My homework was to basically rewrite the methods for a set so it's usable for for a custom class I created called `Square`. I keep getting the error:

```
error: name clash: removeAll(Collection<Square>) in SquareSet and removeAll(Collection<?>) in Set have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
public boolean removeAll(Collection<Square> objects) {
```

I imported both `Set` and `Collection` at the beginning of my code and the class `SquareSet` implements `Set<Square>`.

```
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<Square> objects) {
    Square[] newSet;
    int count = 0;
    for(Square each : objects) {
        count -= 1;
        newSet = new Square[(daSet.length)-count];
        for (int i = 0; i < daSet.length; i++) {
            if (daSet[i].equals(each)) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < daSet.length ; j++) {
                        newSet[j - 1] = daSet[j];
                    }
                } else if (i == ((daSet.length) - 1)) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < daSet.length ; j++) {
                        newSet[j] = daSet[j];
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    newSet[j] = daSet[j];
                    }
                    for (int j = i; j < newSet.length; j++){
                    newSet[j] = daSet[j+1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand a method is overloaded instead of overwritten when the parameter is different from the parameter type I'm overwriting. But I still don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're implementing `Set<Square>`, you'd naturally expect the `removeAll` method to be `removeAll(Collection<Square>)`, but unfortunately in the `Set` interface, the [`removeAll` method is `removeAll(Collection<?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-), with a wildcard instead of the generic type parameter.  This causes your error -- `Collection<Square>` is incompatible with `Collection<?>`.

As for why it's that way, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic) deals with that.  Basically, the designers couldn't get it to work properly when the remove-like methods were fully generified.

To implement the interface properly, you must have your parameter's type be `Collection<?>`.  That means the type of `each` must be `Object`, and you'll have to type-check it to see if it's a `Square`.

In addition, you will want to size your new array more carefully, and only if you have a match to remove from your array.