# Restricting the Object Type for the get method in a Java HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have instantiated my HashMap like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

The datatype of the `Key` is String, so when I try to insert a new key-value pair in the map keeping the `Key` as Integer, it throws an error.

```
myHashMap.put(1L, "value");
```

That means in the put method they have restricted the datatype of the `Key`. But while fetching the value from the map using the `get` method it is not checking for the datatype of the `Key`. So if I write something like this, it doesn't give a compilation error.

```
myHashMap.get(1L);
```

I checked the `get` method in the Java Map interface and its parameter type is `Object`, so that's why it is allowing any Object as the put method argument.

```
V get(Object key)
```

Is there a way I can restrict the datatype which I pass as an argument in the `get` method?

The argument that I pass should have the same datatype as the datatype of the `Key` which I use while instantiating my hashmap.

Comment: No. But good IDEs will warn you when doing that. And you can encapsulate the map into your own class.

Comment: In other languages you could create extension method, like `getTyped...`. In Java you can do this with static method, so your call will be `getTyped(map, key)`. Ugly, but works.

Comment: I have considered the option of creating a wrapper method over the `get` method, something like this:
`Integer getMapValue(Map map, String Key){
return map.get(key)
}
`
And call this method instead of the get method, but I wanted to know if Java provides any such restricting feature of not?

Comment: You can add an implementation of a `get(K key)` method, but It seems like an unnecessary effort. The return value for a mismatching key (type-wise) will be null, as expected. So the Map will conform to its API.

Answer (score 19):

It is designed that way, since during the get operation only the `equals` and `hashCode` is used to determine the object to be returned. The implementation of the `get` method does not check for the type of the Object used as the key.

In your example you are trying to get the value by passing a long like `myHashMap.get(1L);`, firstly the hash code of the object `Long` having the value `1L` will be used to determine the bucket from which to look for. Next the `equals` method of the *key* is used to find out the exact entry of the map from which to return the value. And in a well-defined `equals` method there is always a check for the type:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) { //here type is checked
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

So if the types are not equal, the `equals` method returns `false` and hence `get` also will return `null`.

In some cases such as when using `List` as a key, it may happen that you put an item in the map using an instance of say an `ArrayList` but you can successfully retrieve the same value with an instance of an `LinkedList`. As both implement the `List` interface.

```
Map<List<String>, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
myHashMap.put(arrayList, "foo");
System.out.println(myHashMap.get(linkedList));
```

The above code will output in the console `foo`.

Here although the implementations are different but if you examine the `equals` method of `ArrayList`, it is only checking if the type is a `List`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(o instanceof List)) { //checking type of super interface
            return false;
        }
        ...
}
```

The same is true for `LinkedList`.

Comment: This is a good example of how an answer should be written in StackOverflow - well formulated, informative, with to-the-point code examples. Well done!

Comment: This answer is failing to address the "compilation error" aspect of the question and missing the implicit question of *why* `Map.get` is declared to accept `Object` instead of the `K` parameterized type.

Comment: @Miles that question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic).

Comment: As per the first link @Moira posted the `List` example should have the map type be something like `Map<ArrayList<String>, String>` instead. If the key type is `List<String>` then `V get(K key)` will still work and compile fine with both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. Also this answer does not attempt to answer OP's actual question "Is there a way I can restrict the datatype which I pass as an argument in the `get` method?"

Comment: @SamYonnou with a map defined like this `Map<ArrayList<String>, String>`, `get` with a `LinkedList<String>` instance would still work and retrieve the correct value as in the `equals` method the `instanceof` is done w.r.t to `List` and both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` instances would satisfy that as I mentioned in my answer. And for the actual question many people have already pointed out that it is unnecessary and provided sample code to do it either way. I also explained that with a well defined `equals` method why  it won't be necessary. :)

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick Yes it will work with the standard `V get(Object key)` method. But it would not work cleanly with the theoretical `V get(K key)` method that OP is asking about. In that case you would have to do double casting like `get((ArrayList<String>) (List) myLinkedList)` to get it to compile.

Comment: In any case, OP is asking about why Java uses `V get(Object key)` instead of `V get(K key)` and how to "fix" this lack of type safety (albeit in a roundabout manner). This answer does not seem to be focused on answering that.

Answer (score 4):

I think if it is very important in a project that we control type in HashMap, we could extend HashMap and force using this class instead of HashMap like the below code.

We have all HashMap capabilities, and we should just use the getValue method instead of the get method.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {

    public V getValue(K key) {
        return super.get(key);
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
 public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         MyHashMap<String,Integer> map = new MyHashMap();
     }
 }
```

Comment: A similar answer was posted maybe an hour ago and was then deleted by its poster...........

Comment: I use this approach all the time... i developed this naturally to ensure i can track my map class and not the map implementation. I gives me clarity when navigating the code, but it does not ensure "type safefy"